# Wagtailadmin > return to homepage index after publishing homepage

Tags: wagtail

After publishing a homepage in Wagtail, you are redirected to the index view of the rootpage, not the index view of the homepage.

My question is if it is possible to change the redirect?

Cheers,

Robert

Comment: What is your question? This isn't a blog site, where you post your opinion about something; do that on your own blog. What **specific** programming related question do you have that is on-topic here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with the `after_create_page` / `after_edit_page` hooks:

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.8/reference/hooks.html#after-create-page

These allow you to return a custom HTTP response in place of the redirect that would happen by default. For example, you could do something like:

```py
@hooks.register('after_edit_page')
def redirect_to_homepage_explorer(request, page):
    if page.depth == 2:  # page is an immediate child of root
        # redirect to the current page, instead of its parent
        return redirect('wagtailadmin_explore', page.id)

    # otherwise, return nothing and let the redirect happen as normal
```

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you!

And for those copying the above code, don’t forget to import redirect.

from django.shortcuts import redirect